# How to use typegard for generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I defined following function.

```
const createAction = <I,O>(input: I, conditionFn: (_: I) => boolean, converter: (_: I) => O, restoreFn: (_: O) => any) => {
    if(conditionFn(input)){
        const converted = converter(input);
        return restoreFn(converted);
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

I want to use this function as follows.

```
const conditionAge = (age: number | undefined): age is number => typeof age === 'number';

const convertAge = (age: number) => age + '';

const setAge = (age: number) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_AGE',
        payload: age
    }
};

// mock
const createAge = (value: number, isEmpty: boolean): number | undefined => isEmpty ? undefined : value;

const result = createAction(createAge(33), conditionAge, convertAge, setAge);
// Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

But compile error occurred.
I think generics `I` is not match.
Is there any idea for this issue ??

Comment: Consider using more descriptive type names instead of `I` and `O`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wVYBDGwCCCMAlinALxwA8AknKHsgCapwCKANO1wPIB8ACgBQcUXGLIwAVxgAubiLEBzKdihN5AkPLYBKCnzghxrGh0WikyAG7BYdzQH15NfeUM9zYuFnTRgTvI8bobYyACeQiFwAN4W4gBmcAIqakwCEtIwuvpx3t5W6IgotvZMFMU2dnhQGZIyugDc8d5YMFJQyD7AflgCVqV4TE3xAL7xbR1dUszACRLATM2jzUKF8Knq+ErAFQLYO-LIUgC2AEZ2cAA+cDNMcwvD8ge7xKzH55fucDDhYMAQJIvCjkSgAcg+FygYNW60qg22u0o+0OcEhdmiwIA1HAwTChGsUEVUMAYIi9i95OgoBIlNE8mJJp1Yi0xL9-vIwQBlACiABVHPgAOI8sFefKiMDYcIAGwg2A0cBeYyEKwJcMwODw5OR1mwMqkATRpyhXGAJzAvwqCX1JN0RxNlxudweyEWBnoFqtAH5brN5m7yvI9QbgLCsLgCERSMh+hHtTsBABmJO6LibJiIrgDapZuAksk7JpAA

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for your nice code. This is what I wanted